# writer.writeheader() - Unable to identify fields of a dictionary passed in headers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following code to write a dictionary passed to function to a csv file using python

```
def addToLog(self,content):
    filename = "myfile.csv"
    fileds = content.keys()
    print "Inside Add to Log"
    print fileds
    with open(filename,'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile,fieldnames=fileds)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(content)
```

Here I am trying to get the list of the fields dynamically using the dictionary functions however when I try executing the above file I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'
```

However the keys when printed as mentioned in the above function are as follows:

```
['name', 'dob', 'gender', 'phone', 'email']
```

Unable to spot the issue.

Comment: Content of `content`?

Comment: it is a dictionary

Comment: The fieldnames needs to be list or tuple of strings. Are the keys of `content` string? You might need to use `fileds = list(content.keys())` because the `keys()` method returns a generator, not a sequence.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Comment: @martineau `dict.keys()` returns a `dict_keys` object, which is a sequence type. `DictWriter` takes any sequence type (not only "list or tuple"), and this doesn't have to be a sequence of strings (well, technically at least).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: True (forgot about that) — but my suggestion would still turn it into a `list` that could definitely be used for the `fieldnames` keyword argument.

Comment: @martineau it works as well without it.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Yes, I see the real cause of problem has now been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re attempting to write a single dictionary to a file. For that, use `DictWriter.writerow` rather than `DictWriter.writerows`.

What happens here is that `writerows` (mind the plural ”s“) will attempt to iterate over the `content` to write each element, as it assumes that what you pass in is an iterable of dictionaries. However, if you iterate over a single dictionary, you’ll get its keys, each of which is not a dictionary that holds the field names you mentioned upon creating the DictWriter.